# Multidimensional ROI of Multidimesional cv::Mat in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, multidimensional-array, roi

I'm using OpenCV in C++ to create a multidimensional mat (to use as an accumulator) over an image.

I create the 3d accumulator like this:

```
const int accumSize[] = {sx, sy, sr};
cv::Mat accum(3, accumSize, CV_64F, cv::Scalar::all(0));
```

I need to extract an `n*n*n` ROI from this accumulator so I can get the maximum within each ROI using `cv::minMaxIdx`.

Since this is 3d, the usual method of using a `cv::Rect` to get the ROI doesn't work. Nor does:

```
accum(cv::Range(x1,x2), cv::Range(y1,y2), cv::Range(r1,r2));
```

Anyone know how to easily get a 3d submatrix without having to explicitly allocate it and copy element by element?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `()` operator, however you need to provide an array of ranges, like this:

```
cv::Range ranges[3];
ranges[0] = cv::Range(x1, x2);
ranges[1] = cv::Range(y1, y2);
ranges[2] = cv::Range(z1, z2);

accum(ranges)
```

Comment: Note that using ranges seem to be a different order. If my Rect was `Rect(x,y,w,h)`, then the Ranges for those first two dimensions would have to be ordered: `{Range(y, y+h), Range(x, x+w), ...}`

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you are working with `n` channels and each channel has a matrix of `a x b`. Merge these channels to create a new `Mat` of `depth = n` and `size = a x b`. Use Rect to define and crop the ROI.

```
vector<Mat> channels;

// populate this vector with number of channels you desire

Mat mergedChannels, croppedChannels;
Rect roi(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1);

merge(channels, mergedChannels);
croppedChannels = mergedChannels(roi);

printf("%d %d %d\n", croppedChannels.cols, croppedChannels.rows, croppedChannels.channels());
```

Comment: This doesn't work unless the channels are all contained in one element of the cv::Mat's datatype.